# Consequences of P(A/B)=P(B/A)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

if A and B are two events and P(A/B) = P(B/A) then I want to know how A and B are related to each other?. i.e. are they
1) exclusive events  or 
2) independent events or
3) exhaustive events
4) is it P(A) = P(B)

please let me know the answer with corresponding justification?
Rectify me if I am wrong anywhere

Comment: Are these conditional probabilities? If so I suggest you consider Baye's Theorem.

Comment: @Jimmy Yes,they are conditional probabilities. Bayes Theorem for this ,Sorry , I didn't get you.

Comment: @manikanta you may want to ask this on [stats.SE] instead.

Answer (score 2):

Bayes' Theorem states that:

```
P(A|B) = P(B|A) x P(A) / P(B)
```

So if P(A|B) = P(B|A) and is non-zero:

```
P(A) = P(B)
```

Comment: Nit-picky, but it is [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem), not Baye's.